# Prove: If $\{a_n / n\}$ converges to L which is not 0, then $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: If $\{a_n / n\}$ $\rightarrow$ L $\neq$ 0, then $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded.

I've been working on this problem a while, and I've been having trouble relating ${a_n / n}$ and $\{a_n\}$. I know $\{a_n / n\}$ $<$ $\{a_n\}$ but I can't get it using only basic limit theorems like the ones I've listed below.

Every convergent sequence is bounded.

A sequence that is not bounded can never converge.

If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converge to $A$ and $B$, respectively, and if $\{a_n\}$ $\le$ $\{b_n\}$ for every $n$ $\in$ **$N$**, then $A$ $\le$ $B$.

Answer (score 3):

We can work straight from definitions. Since $a_n/n\to L\ne 0$, we have some $N$ such that for $n>N$, $|a_n/n-L|<|L/2|$. Thus $|a_n/n|>|L|-|L/2|=|L/2|$, so $|a_n|>n|L/2|$, which is clearly unbounded, so $a_n$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove a sequence unbounded, you need to show that for any $N$ I give you, you can find an $a_n$ with $|a_n| \gt N$.  You are given that $\frac {a_n}n$ is close to $L$ (at least for large $n$).  That tells you $a_n$ is close to $nL$. It should look to you that that diverges.  Can you flesh this out -I give you $N$, you choose an $\epsilon$ (it doesn't really matter what) and ask for an $m$ for which $|\frac {a_n}n -L|\lt \epsilon$ as long as $n \gt m$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the squeeze theorem to obtain a contradiction. If $|a_n|\leq c$, then $-c/n\leq a_n/n\leq c/n$. But $c/n\rightarrow 0$ so by squeeze theorem $a_n/n\rightarrow 0$, contradiction.