# Prove that if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n \over n} = L \ne 0$, then $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

I'm a little stuck on how to complete the proof:

> Prove that if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n \over n} = L \ne 0$, then $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is unbounded.

There is an answer already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754342/prove-if-a-n-n-converges-to-l-which-is-not-0-then-a-n-is-unbound), but I don't completely understand the logic of how they conclude

> $$\left|{s_n \over n} - L\right| < {1 \over 2} |L| \implies \left|{s_n \over n}\right| > |L| - {1 \over 2}|L|.$$

Obviously, we may choose $\epsilon = {1\over2}|L| > 0$ since $L \ne 0$. But it is not immediately clear why the implication follows. I'm inclined to say the Triangle Inequality was used, but I don't know how exactly. Can someone provide a hint to how the implication was derived?

**EDIT:** The problem I was having that was making this difficult was that I knew that $$\left|{s_n \over n}\right| - |L| \le \left|{s_n \over n} - L\right| < {1 \over 2}|L| \implies \left|{s_n \over n}\right| < {3\over2 }|L|,$$ which shows that $|s_n| < {3 \over 2}n|L|$. This confused me because it didn't seem entirely clear that the sequence would be unbounded. However, with the aid of the reverse triangle inequality, we can write $$\left|\left|{s_n \over n}\right| - |L|\right| \le \left|{s_n \over n} - L\right| < {1 \over 2}|L|,$$ which $\displaystyle\left|\left|{s_n \over n}\right| - |L|\right| \le \left|{s_n \over n} - L\right|$ gives us another inequality to work with which *will* show that the sequence is unbounded. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality),
$$
|L|-\biggl|\frac{s_n}n\biggr|\le\biggl||L|-\biggl|\frac{s_n}n\biggr|\biggr|\le\biggl|L-\frac{s_n}n\biggr|=\biggl|\frac{s_n}n-L\biggr|.
$$
Hence,
$$
|L|-\biggl|\frac{s_n}n\biggr|<\frac{|L|}2
$$
and
$$
\biggl|\frac{s_n}n\biggr|>\frac{|L|}2.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten that $\displaystyle \left|{s_n \over n} - L\right| = \left|L - {s_n \over n}\right|$. This completes the argument, making it completely evident why the implication is true. Since I did not see this, I had quite a difficult time getting the inequality to go in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse triangle inequality: $$\left|\frac{s_n}{n}-L\right|=\left|L-\frac{s_n}{n}\right|\ge \left|L\right|-\left|\frac{s_n}{n}\right|$$

Comment: I greatly appreciate this answer. I wish I could choose two correct answers!